# Extract subdomains from strings using split in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

I have a python function that outputs/prints the following:

```
['CN=*.something1.net', 'CN=*.something2.net', 'CN=*.something4.net', 'CN=something6.net', 'CN=something8.net', 'CN=intranet.something89.net', 'CN=intranet.something111.net, 'OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain, CN=something99.net', 'OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=intranet.something66.net',...etc]
```

I am trying to extract all the sub-domain names between "CN=" and the single quotation mark, using the split() method in python. I've tried `split('CN=', 1)[0]`  but i can't get my head around on how to use it

what i want to print out:

```
['something1.net', 'something2.net', 'something4.net', 'intranet.something111.net', 'intranet.something66.net']
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated :-)

Thanks, MJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last single quote is indicating the end of the string, so it seems you just want everything after `CN=`. Assuming that's the case, you can just chop off the first three characters:

```
subdomains = [item[3:] for item in my_list if item.startswith('CN=')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more readable code that extracts the subdomains in more clean or better way;
@tzaman code didn't really give me subdomains.

```
myDirtyDomains = ['CN=*.something1.net', 'CN=*.something2.net', 'CN=*.something4.net',\
'CN=something6.net', 'CN=something8.net', 'CN=intranet.something89.net',\
 'CN=intranet.something111.net', 'OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain', \
 'CN=something99.net', 'OU=Domain Control Validated', 'CN=intranet.something66.net']

cleanSubDomainsList = []

for item in myDirtyDomains:
    countDots = item.count(".")
    if countDots == 2:
        host = item.partition('CN=')[2]
        subdomain = host.partition('.')[0]
        cleanSubDomainsList.append(subdomain)

print(cleanSubDomainsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to strip `CN=` from each string, you can strip from the left with [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
subdomains = [item.lstrip("CN=") for item in my_list]
```